# Push to another server based on incoming url

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, http-live-streaming, rtmp

Playing around with nginx and wanted to know if there was a way to take an incoming RTMP stream and redirect it to another server based on the URL used. For example:

rtmp://ingress.foo.com/live/<stream_key> would forward to rtmp://<stream_key>.internal.foo.com

Thanks.

Comment: Not in ffmpeg directly. You have to script it externally and pass the URL to ffmpeg.

Comment: How would you pass it back to ffmpeg? Do you have any examples?

Comment: e.g. a variable in a shell script.

Comment: I guess I mean how do you pass it back to nginx to push?